# GetWindow API VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, api, winapi

I usually write scripts in the VBE of Excel because they all tend to involve Excel. This time I wrote a script which has nothing to do with Excel, so I want to make it an executable file.

Note:
 - Below code is a part of the actual script
 - I tested this part also separately in the VBE and it works
 - I tried it now in Visual Studio 2015

Problem:
 - The code returns the handle of lWindow, but always returns 0 voor lChild

```
Module Module1
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String,
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (
     ByVal hwnd As Long,
     ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const GW_CHILD = 5
Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5&

Sub Main()
    Dim lWindow As Long
    Dim lChild As Long

    lWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Untitled - Notepad")
    Debug.Print(lWindow)
    lChild = GetWindow(lWindow, GW_CHILD)
    Debug.Print(lChild)
End Sub
```

End Module

Thanks.

Comment: `GetWindow` isn't horribly reliable.  I'd use `EnumChildWindows` instead.

Comment: Update any vba/vb6 PInvokes using http://www.pinvoke.net/ Most of those `Long` vars ought to be Int32 in .NET